# Which Linux distros support VMWare's autofit guest feature?

Tags: resolution, vmware

I currently have two VM's with my VMWare Workstation 10.0.1:

*Linux Mint (Cinnamon)* and *Lubuntu (LXDE)*. The host system is Windows 8.1. With Mint, the auto fit guest feature works after installing the VMWare tools and rebooting. I can resize as I please and extend to multiple monitors. All works. With Lubuntu however, nothing works. I have to adjust the resolution manually, and oddly enough 1920x1080 is missing entirely.

I searched for a solution and I guess I could hack something with xrandr, but that seems like too much trouble.

Could someone please tell me:

1) Why does auto fit guest work with some distros and not with others? Is this dependent on the GUI that is used? (Cinnamon vs. LXDE)

2) Which distros/GUIs **do** support the feature out of the box?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, since no one is answering I'll be left to do some trial and error. I'll update this post when I discover new distros that work:

**Auto fit worked** after installing VMWare tools

- Linux Mint 15 (Cinnnamon)
- Xubuntu 12.04.3 (XFCE)
- Kubuntu 13.10 (KDE)

**Autofit does not work**, even with VMWare tools

- Lubuntu 13.10 (LXDE)